# Apache Ignite: Slow Node join and failure

Tags: java, ignite

We have a Ignite setup with 3 Servers and Persistence and therefore Baselining enabled. From time to time we have the issue that the Servers take a long time to rebuild the cluster after all Nodes are restarted. Ignite runs embedded in the application.

```
20.11.2020 08:18:17.678 WARN  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.util.typedef.G:290      - Ignite work directory is not provided, automatically resolved to: D:\IntegrationSolutions\Services\LabDeviceHUB\Labbox\.\..\userdata\labbox\ignite\work
20.11.2020 08:18:17.709 WARN  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.util.typedef.G:295      - Consistent ID is not set, it is recommended to set consistent ID for production clusters (use IgniteConfiguration.setConsistentId property)
20.11.2020 08:18:18.053 INFO  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:285        - Config URL: n/a
20.11.2020 08:18:18.084 INFO  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:285        - IgniteConfiguration [igniteInstanceName=null, pubPoolSize=8, svcPoolSize=8, callbackPoolSize=8, stripedPoolSize=8, sysPoolSize=8, mgmtPoolSize=4, igfsPoolSize=4, dataStreamerPoolSize=8, utilityCachePoolSize=8, utilityCacheKeepAliveTime=60000, p2pPoolSize=2, qryPoolSize=8, sqlQryHistSize=1000, dfltQryTimeout=0, igniteHome=D:\IntegrationSolutions\Services\LabDeviceHUB\Labbox\.\..\userdata\labbox\ignite, igniteWorkDir=D:\IntegrationSolutions\Services\LabDeviceHUB\Labbox\.\..\userdata\labbox\ignite\work, mbeanSrv=com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@78c03f1f, nodeId=0e60d50b-ee2e-46ed-8d76-5cb51791011b, marsh=BinaryMarshaller [], marshLocJobs=false, daemon=false, p2pEnabled=true, netTimeout=5000, netCompressionLevel=1, sndRetryDelay=1000, sndRetryCnt=3, metricsHistSize=10000, metricsUpdateFreq=2000, metricsExpTime=9223372036854775807, discoSpi=TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=0, ackTimeout=0, marsh=null, reconCnt=10, reconDelay=2000, maxAckTimeout=600000, soLinger=5, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false, internalLsnr=null, skipAddrsRandomization=false], segPlc=STOP, segResolveAttempts=2, waitForSegOnStart=true, allResolversPassReq=true, segChkFreq=10000, commSpi=TcpCommunicationSpi [connectGate=null, connPlc=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$FirstConnectionPolicy@522ba524, chConnPlc=null, enableForcibleNodeKill=false, enableTroubleshootingLog=false, locAddr=null, locHost=null, locPort=47100, locPortRange=100, shmemPort=-1, directBuf=true, directSndBuf=false, idleConnTimeout=600000, connTimeout=5000, maxConnTimeout=600000, reconCnt=10, sockSndBuf=32768, sockRcvBuf=32768, msgQueueLimit=0, slowClientQueueLimit=0, nioSrvr=null, shmemSrv=null, usePairedConnections=false, connectionsPerNode=1, tcpNoDelay=true, filterReachableAddresses=false, ackSndThreshold=32, unackedMsgsBufSize=0, sockWriteTimeout=2000, boundTcpPort=-1, boundTcpShmemPort=-1, selectorsCnt=4, selectorSpins=0, addrRslvr=null, ctxInitLatch=java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@29c5ee1d[Count = 1], stopping=false, metricsLsnr=null], evtSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.eventstorage.NoopEventStorageSpi@15cea7b0, colSpi=NoopCollisionSpi [], deploySpi=LocalDeploymentSpi [], indexingSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.indexing.noop.NoopIndexingSpi@1e6cc850, addrRslvr=null, encryptionSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.encryption.noop.NoopEncryptionSpi@7e7f0f0a, clientMode=false, rebalanceThreadPoolSize=4, rebalanceTimeout=10000, rebalanceBatchesPrefetchCnt=3, rebalanceThrottle=0, rebalanceBatchSize=524288, txCfg=TransactionConfiguration [txSerEnabled=false, dfltIsolation=REPEATABLE_READ, dfltConcurrency=PESSIMISTIC, dfltTxTimeout=0, txTimeoutOnPartitionMapExchange=0, deadlockTimeout=10000, pessimisticTxLogSize=0, pessimisticTxLogLinger=10000, tmLookupClsName=null, txManagerFactory=null, useJtaSync=false], cacheSanityCheckEnabled=true, discoStartupDelay=60000, deployMode=SHARED, p2pMissedCacheSize=100, locHost=null, timeSrvPortBase=31100, timeSrvPortRange=100, failureDetectionTimeout=10000, sysWorkerBlockedTimeout=null, clientFailureDetectionTimeout=30000, metricsLogFreq=0, hadoopCfg=null, connectorCfg=ConnectorConfiguration [jettyPath=null, host=null, port=11211, noDelay=true, directBuf=false, sndBufSize=32768, rcvBufSize=32768, idleQryCurTimeout=600000, idleQryCurCheckFreq=60000, sndQueueLimit=0, selectorCnt=4, idleTimeout=7000, sslEnabled=false, sslClientAuth=false, sslCtxFactory=null, sslFactory=null, portRange=100, threadPoolSize=8, msgInterceptor=null], odbcCfg=null, warmupClos=null, atomicCfg=AtomicConfiguration [seqReserveSize=1000, cacheMode=PARTITIONED, backups=1, aff=null, grpName=null], classLdr=null, sslCtxFactory=null, platformCfg=null, binaryCfg=null, memCfg=null, pstCfg=null, dsCfg=DataStorageConfiguration [sysRegionInitSize=10485760, sysRegionMaxSize=52428800, pageSize=0, concLvl=0, dfltDataRegConf=DataRegionConfiguration [name=default, maxSize=858886144, initSize=10485760, swapPath=null, pageEvictionMode=DISABLED, evictionThreshold=0.9, emptyPagesPoolSize=100, metricsEnabled=true, metricsSubIntervalCount=5, metricsRateTimeInterval=60000, persistenceEnabled=true, checkpointPageBufSize=0, lazyMemoryAllocation=true], dataRegions=DataRegionConfiguration[] [DataRegionConfiguration [name=persistent, maxSize=52428800, initSize=10485760, swapPath=null, pageEvictionMode=DISABLED, evictionThreshold=0.9, emptyPagesPoolSize=100, metricsEnabled=true, metricsSubIntervalCount=5, metricsRateTimeInterval=60000, persistenceEnabled=true, checkpointPageBufSize=0, lazyMemoryAllocation=true]], storagePath=null, checkpointFreq=180000, lockWaitTime=10000, checkpointThreads=4, checkpointWriteOrder=SEQUENTIAL, walHistSize=20, maxWalArchiveSize=1073741824, walSegments=4, walSegmentSize=10485760, walPath=db/wal, walArchivePath=db/wal/archive, metricsEnabled=false, walMode=LOG_ONLY, walTlbSize=131072, walBuffSize=0, walFlushFreq=2000, walFsyncDelay=1000, walRecordIterBuffSize=67108864, alwaysWriteFullPages=false, fileIOFactory=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.file.AsyncFileIOFactory@59429fac, metricsSubIntervalCnt=5, metricsRateTimeInterval=60000, walAutoArchiveAfterInactivity=-1, writeThrottlingEnabled=false, walCompactionEnabled=false, walCompactionLevel=1, checkpointReadLockTimeout=null, walPageCompression=DISABLED, walPageCompressionLevel=null], activeOnStart=true, autoActivation=true, longQryWarnTimeout=3000, sqlConnCfg=null, cliConnCfg=ClientConnectorConfiguration [host=null, port=10800, portRange=100, sockSndBufSize=0, sockRcvBufSize=0, tcpNoDelay=true, maxOpenCursorsPerConn=128, threadPoolSize=8, idleTimeout=0, handshakeTimeout=10000, jdbcEnabled=true, odbcEnabled=true, thinCliEnabled=true, sslEnabled=false, useIgniteSslCtxFactory=true, sslClientAuth=false, sslCtxFactory=null, thinCliCfg=ThinClientConfiguration [maxActiveTxPerConn=100]], mvccVacuumThreadCnt=2, mvccVacuumFreq=5000, authEnabled=false, failureHnd=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]], commFailureRslvr=null]
20.11.2020 08:18:18.084 INFO  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:285        - Daemon mode: off
...
20.11.2020 08:18:18.100 INFO  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:285        - Remote Management [restart: off, REST: on, JMX (remote: on, port: 8071, auth: off, ssl: off)]
20.11.2020 08:18:18.100 INFO  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:285        - Logger: JavaLogger [quiet=true, config=null]
20.11.2020 08:18:18.100 INFO  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:285        - IGNITE_HOME=D:\IntegrationSolutions\Services\LabDeviceHUB\Labbox\.\..\userdata\labbox\ignite
20.11.2020 08:18:18.100 INFO  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:285        - VM arguments: [-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8071, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false, -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=log/dump.hprof, -XX:+UseG1GC, -XX:+UseStringDeduplication, --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-exports=java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-exports=jdk.internal.jvmstat/sun.jvmstat.monitor=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-exports=java.base/sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects=ALL-UNNAMED, --illegal-access=permit, -Xmx500m]
20.11.2020 08:18:18.100 INFO  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:285        - System cache's DataRegion size is configured to 10 MB. Use DataStorageConfiguration.systemRegionInitialSize property to change the setting.
20.11.2020 08:18:18.100 INFO  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:285        - Configured caches [in 'sysMemPlc' dataRegion: ['ignite-sys-cache']]
20.11.2020 08:18:18.100 WARN  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:295        - Peer class loading is enabled (disable it in production for performance and deployment consistency reasons)
20.11.2020 08:18:18.100 WARN  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:295        - Please set system property '-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true' to avoid possible problems in mixed environments.
20.11.2020 08:18:18.100 INFO  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:285        - 3-rd party licenses can be found at: D:\IntegrationSolutions\Services\LabDeviceHUB\Labbox\.\..\userdata\labbox\ignite\libs\licenses
20.11.2020 08:18:18.100 INFO  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:285        - Local node user attribute [BUILD_VERSION=2.1.4]
20.11.2020 08:18:18.100 INFO  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:285        - Local node user attribute [NODE_NAME=EESRV-LBXC03]
20.11.2020 08:18:18.100 INFO  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:285        - Local node user attribute [BUILD_NUMBER=848]
20.11.2020 08:18:18.100 INFO  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:285        - Local node user attribute [NODE_TYPE=LABBOX]
20.11.2020 08:18:18.100 INFO  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:285        - Local node user attribute [VERSION=0]
20.11.2020 08:18:18.100 INFO  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:285        - Local node user attribute [BUILD_TIME=1604577743000]
20.11.2020 08:18:18.100 INFO  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:285        - Local node user attribute [APPLICATION_NAME=Labbox]
20.11.2020 08:18:18.100 INFO  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:285        - Local node user attribute [BUILD_GIT_HASH=ff2f1f3]
20.11.2020 08:18:18.100 INFO  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:285        - Local node user attribute [KEY=_OL2;f~.C3n}yo6p<Zx=BE4I2P:lDL"f]
20.11.2020 08:18:18.163 WARN  [pub-#19] org.apache.ignite.internal.GridDiagnostic:295      - This operating system has been tested less rigorously: Windows Server 2012 R2 6.3 amd64. Our team will appreciate the feedback if you experience any problems running ignite in this environment.
20.11.2020 08:18:18.163 WARN  [pub-#22] org.apache.ignite.internal.GridDiagnostic:295      - Initial heap size is 64MB (should be no less than 512MB, use -Xms512m -Xmx512m).
20.11.2020 08:18:18.334 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.plugin.IgnitePluginProcessor:285         - Configured plugins:
20.11.2020 08:18:18.334 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.plugin.IgnitePluginProcessor:285         -   ^-- Authentication 1.0.0
20.11.2020 08:18:18.334 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.plugin.IgnitePluginProcessor:285         -   ^-- null
20.11.2020 08:18:18.334 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.plugin.IgnitePluginProcessor:285         - 
20.11.2020 08:18:18.334 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.processors.failure.FailureProcessor:285    - Configured failure handler: [hnd=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]]
20.11.2020 08:18:18.600 INFO  [main] o.a.i.s.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi:285  - Successfully bound communication NIO server to TCP port [port=47100, locHost=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0, selectorsCnt=4, selectorSpins=0, pairedConn=false]
20.11.2020 08:18:18.678 WARN  [main] o.a.i.s.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi:295  - Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.
20.11.2020 08:18:18.694 WARN  [main] o.a.i.spi.checkpoint.noop.NoopCheckpointSpi:295    - Checkpoints are disabled (to enable configure any GridCheckpointSpi implementation)
20.11.2020 08:18:18.741 WARN  [main] o.a.i.i.m.collision.GridCollisionManager:295       - Collision resolution is disabled (all jobs will be activated upon arrival).
20.11.2020 08:18:18.741 INFO  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:285        - Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]
20.11.2020 08:18:18.866 INFO  [main] o.a.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi:285   - Successfully bound to TCP port [port=47500, localHost=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0, locNodeId=0e60d50b-ee2e-46ed-8d76-5cb51791011b]
20.11.2020 08:18:18.866 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.filename.PdsFoldersResolver:285      - Successfully locked persistence storage folder [D:\IntegrationSolutions\Services\LabDeviceHUB\Labbox\.\..\userdata\labbox\ignite\work\db\node00-1dbddb2c-ef76-4811-b7d3-46da82061bc5]
20.11.2020 08:18:18.866 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.filename.PdsFoldersResolver:285      - Consistent ID used for local node is [1dbddb2c-ef76-4811-b7d3-46da82061bc5] according to persistence data storage folders
20.11.2020 08:18:18.866 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.b.CacheObjectBinaryProcessorImpl:285   - Resolved directory for serialized binary metadata: D:\IntegrationSolutions\Services\LabDeviceHUB\Labbox\.\..\userdata\labbox\ignite\work\binary_meta\node00-1dbddb2c-ef76-4811-b7d3-46da82061bc5
20.11.2020 08:18:19.631 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.file.FilePageStoreManager:285        - Resolved page store work directory: D:\IntegrationSolutions\Services\LabDeviceHUB\Labbox\.\..\userdata\labbox\ignite\work\db\node00-1dbddb2c-ef76-4811-b7d3-46da82061bc5
20.11.2020 08:18:19.694 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.w.f.FileHandleManagerImpl:285        - Initialized write-ahead log manager [mode=LOG_ONLY]
20.11.2020 08:18:19.772 WARN  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager:295   - DataRegionConfiguration.maxWalArchiveSize instead DataRegionConfiguration.walHistorySize would be used for removing old archive wal files
20.11.2020 08:18:19.803 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager:285   - Configured data regions initialized successfully [total=5]
20.11.2020 08:18:19.834 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.d.d.t.PartitionsEvictManager:285       - Evict partition permits=2
20.11.2020 08:18:19.850 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.odbc.ClientListenerProcessor:285         - Client connector processor has started on TCP port 10800
20.11.2020 08:18:20.006 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.r.protocols.tcp.GridTcpRestProtocol:285  - Command protocol successfully started [name=TCP binary, host=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0, port=11211]
20.11.2020 08:18:20.115 INFO  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:285        - Non-loopback local IPs: 192.168.92.177, fe80:0:0:0:6859:37c8:f543:8087%eth4
20.11.2020 08:18:20.115 INFO  [main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal:285        - Enabled local MACs: 00000000000000E0, 005056BD5072
20.11.2020 08:18:20.131 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager:285   - Read checkpoint status [startMarker=D:\IntegrationSolutions\Services\LabDeviceHUB\Labbox\.\..\userdata\labbox\ignite\work\db\node00-1dbddb2c-ef76-4811-b7d3-46da82061bc5\cp\1605855371041-8b5aaf2a-7867-47b0-879c-85791363041f-START.bin, endMarker=D:\IntegrationSolutions\Services\LabDeviceHUB\Labbox\.\..\userdata\labbox\ignite\work\db\node00-1dbddb2c-ef76-4811-b7d3-46da82061bc5\cp\1605855371041-8b5aaf2a-7867-47b0-879c-85791363041f-END.bin]
20.11.2020 08:18:20.147 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.pagemem.PageMemoryImpl:285           - Started page memory [memoryAllocated=50,0 MiB, pages=12404, tableSize=988,2 KiB, checkpointBuffer=50,0 MiB]
20.11.2020 08:18:20.147 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager:285   - Checking memory state [lastValidPos=FileWALPointer [idx=512, fileOff=3672982, len=99269], lastMarked=FileWALPointer [idx=512, fileOff=3672982, len=99269], lastCheckpointId=8b5aaf2a-7867-47b0-879c-85791363041f]
20.11.2020 08:18:20.225 WARN  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager:290     - WAL segment tail reached. [idx=512, isWorkDir=true, serVer=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.serializer.RecordV2Serializer@5853495b, actualFilePtr=FileWALPointer [idx=512, fileOff=3772251, len=0]]
20.11.2020 08:18:20.256 WARN  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager:290     - WAL segment tail reached. [idx=512, isWorkDir=true, serVer=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.serializer.RecordV2Serializer@21f459fc, actualFilePtr=FileWALPointer [idx=512, fileOff=3772251, len=0]]
20.11.2020 08:18:20.256 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager:285   - Found last checkpoint marker [cpId=8b5aaf2a-7867-47b0-879c-85791363041f, pos=FileWALPointer [idx=512, fileOff=3672982, len=99269]]
20.11.2020 08:18:20.350 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager:285   - Applying lost cache updates since last checkpoint record [lastMarked=FileWALPointer [idx=512, fileOff=3672982, len=99269], lastCheckpointId=8b5aaf2a-7867-47b0-879c-85791363041f]
20.11.2020 08:18:20.365 WARN  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager:290     - WAL segment tail reached. [idx=512, isWorkDir=true, serVer=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.serializer.RecordV2Serializer@6c15e8c7, actualFilePtr=FileWALPointer [idx=512, fileOff=3772251, len=0]]
20.11.2020 08:18:20.381 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager:285   - Finished applying WAL changes [updatesApplied=0, time=31 ms]
20.11.2020 08:18:20.381 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor:285    - Restoring partition state for local groups.
20.11.2020 08:18:20.381 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor:285    - Finished restoring partition state for local groups [groupsProcessed=0, partitionsProcessed=0, time=0ms]
20.11.2020 08:18:20.412 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.cluster.GridClusterStateProcessor:285    - Restoring history for BaselineTopology[id=12]
20.11.2020 08:18:20.522 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.c.DistributedBaselineConfiguration:285     - Baseline parameter 'baselineAutoAdjustEnabled' was changed from 'null' to 'true'
20.11.2020 08:18:20.522 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.c.DistributedBaselineConfiguration:285     - Baseline parameter 'baselineAutoAdjustTimeout' was changed from 'null' to '300000'
20.11.2020 08:18:20.522 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.file.FilePageStoreManager:285        - Cleanup cache stores [total=1, left=0, cleanFiles=false]
20.11.2020 08:18:20.522 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.pagemem.PageMemoryImpl:285           - Started page memory [memoryAllocated=50,0 MiB, pages=12404, tableSize=988,2 KiB, checkpointBuffer=50,0 MiB]
20.11.2020 08:18:20.537 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.pagemem.PageMemoryImpl:285           - Started page memory [memoryAllocated=50,0 MiB, pages=12404, tableSize=988,2 KiB, checkpointBuffer=50,0 MiB]
20.11.2020 08:18:20.537 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.pagemem.PageMemoryImpl:285           - Started page memory [memoryAllocated=50,0 MiB, pages=12404, tableSize=988,2 KiB, checkpointBuffer=50,0 MiB]
20.11.2020 08:18:20.537 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager:285   - Configured data regions started successfully [total=5]
20.11.2020 08:18:20.537 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager:285   - Starting binary memory restore for: [166757441, -1947899996, -8785046, -2100569601, 1793235927, -499392514, 30677022, 129211407, 1139332309, 1725334265]
20.11.2020 08:18:21.334 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager:285   - Read checkpoint status [startMarker=D:\IntegrationSolutions\Services\LabDeviceHUB\Labbox\.\..\userdata\labbox\ignite\work\db\node00-1dbddb2c-ef76-4811-b7d3-46da82061bc5\cp\1605855371041-8b5aaf2a-7867-47b0-879c-85791363041f-START.bin, endMarker=D:\IntegrationSolutions\Services\LabDeviceHUB\Labbox\.\..\userdata\labbox\ignite\work\db\node00-1dbddb2c-ef76-4811-b7d3-46da82061bc5\cp\1605855371041-8b5aaf2a-7867-47b0-879c-85791363041f-END.bin]
20.11.2020 08:18:21.334 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager:285   - Checking memory state [lastValidPos=FileWALPointer [idx=512, fileOff=3672982, len=99269], lastMarked=FileWALPointer [idx=512, fileOff=3672982, len=99269], lastCheckpointId=8b5aaf2a-7867-47b0-879c-85791363041f]
20.11.2020 08:18:21.365 WARN  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager:290     - WAL segment tail reached. [idx=512, isWorkDir=true, serVer=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.serializer.RecordV2Serializer@317e9c3c, actualFilePtr=FileWALPointer [idx=512, fileOff=3772251, len=0]]
20.11.2020 08:18:21.397 WARN  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager:290     - WAL segment tail reached. [idx=512, isWorkDir=true, serVer=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.serializer.RecordV2Serializer@31a3f4de, actualFilePtr=FileWALPointer [idx=512, fileOff=3772251, len=0]]
20.11.2020 08:18:21.397 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager:285   - Found last checkpoint marker [cpId=8b5aaf2a-7867-47b0-879c-85791363041f, pos=FileWALPointer [idx=512, fileOff=3672982, len=99269]]
20.11.2020 08:18:21.412 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager:285   - Binary memory state restored at node startup [restoredPtr=FileWALPointer [idx=512, fileOff=3772251, len=0]]
20.11.2020 08:18:21.428 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.pagemem.PageMemoryImpl:285           - Started page memory [memoryAllocated=50,0 MiB, pages=12404, tableSize=988,2 KiB, checkpointBuffer=50,0 MiB]
20.11.2020 08:18:21.568 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor:285    - Started cache in recovery mode [name=license, id=166757441, dataRegionName=persistent, mode=REPLICATED, atomicity=ATOMIC, backups=2147483647, mvcc=false]
20.11.2020 08:18:21.584 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.pagemem.PageMemoryImpl:285           - Started page memory [memoryAllocated=819,1 MiB, pages=203256, tableSize=15,8 MiB, checkpointBuffer=256,0 MiB]
20.11.2020 08:18:21.584 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor:285    - Started cache in recovery mode [name=commservices, id=-8785046, dataRegionName=default, mode=REPLICATED, atomicity=ATOMIC, backups=2147483647, mvcc=false]
20.11.2020 08:18:21.615 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor:285    - Started cache in recovery mode [name=ignite-sys-cache, id=-2100569601, dataRegionName=sysMemPlc, mode=REPLICATED, atomicity=TRANSACTIONAL, backups=2147483647, mvcc=false]
20.11.2020 08:18:21.615 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor:285    - Started cache in recovery mode [name=machinespecifications, id=1793235927, dataRegionName=persistent, mode=REPLICATED, atomicity=ATOMIC, backups=2147483647, mvcc=false]
20.11.2020 08:18:21.615 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor:285    - Started cache in recovery mode [name=nxisPorts, id=-499392514, dataRegionName=persistent, mode=REPLICATED, atomicity=ATOMIC, backups=2147483647, mvcc=false]
20.11.2020 08:18:21.631 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor:285    - Started cache in recovery mode [name=datastructures_ATOMIC_PARTITIONED_1@labqueue, id=1205724040, group=labqueue, dataRegionName=default, mode=PARTITIONED, atomicity=ATOMIC, backups=1, mvcc=false]
20.11.2020 08:18:21.631 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor:285    - Started cache in recovery mode [name=ignite-sys-atomic-cache@labqueue, id=-327698687, group=labqueue, dataRegionName=default, mode=PARTITIONED, atomicity=TRANSACTIONAL, backups=1, mvcc=false]
20.11.2020 08:18:21.631 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor:285    - Started cache in recovery mode [name=machinemaxbatchno, id=30677022, dataRegionName=persistent, mode=PARTITIONED, atomicity=ATOMIC, backups=1, mvcc=false]
20.11.2020 08:18:21.646 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor:285    - Started cache in recovery mode [name=machineconfiguration, id=129211407, dataRegionName=persistent, mode=REPLICATED, atomicity=ATOMIC, backups=2147483647, mvcc=false]
20.11.2020 08:18:21.646 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor:285    - Started cache in recovery mode [name=specimentracer, id=1139332309, dataRegionName=persistent, mode=PARTITIONED, atomicity=ATOMIC, backups=1, mvcc=false]
20.11.2020 08:18:21.646 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor:285    - Started cache in recovery mode [name=machinestatus, id=1725334265, dataRegionName=default, mode=PARTITIONED, atomicity=ATOMIC, backups=1, mvcc=false]
20.11.2020 08:18:21.646 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager:285   - Binary recovery performed in 1109 ms.
20.11.2020 08:18:21.646 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager:285   - Read checkpoint status [startMarker=D:\IntegrationSolutions\Services\LabDeviceHUB\Labbox\.\..\userdata\labbox\ignite\work\db\node00-1dbddb2c-ef76-4811-b7d3-46da82061bc5\cp\1605855371041-8b5aaf2a-7867-47b0-879c-85791363041f-START.bin, endMarker=D:\IntegrationSolutions\Services\LabDeviceHUB\Labbox\.\..\userdata\labbox\ignite\work\db\node00-1dbddb2c-ef76-4811-b7d3-46da82061bc5\cp\1605855371041-8b5aaf2a-7867-47b0-879c-85791363041f-END.bin]
20.11.2020 08:18:21.662 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager:285   - Applying lost cache updates since last checkpoint record [lastMarked=FileWALPointer [idx=512, fileOff=3672982, len=99269], lastCheckpointId=8b5aaf2a-7867-47b0-879c-85791363041f]
20.11.2020 08:18:21.693 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager:285   - Finished applying WAL changes [updatesApplied=0, time=31 ms]
20.11.2020 08:18:21.693 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor:285    - Restoring partition state for local groups.
20.11.2020 08:18:21.943 INFO  [main] o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor:285    - Finished restoring partition state for local groups [groupsProcessed=10, partitionsProcessed=5220, time=235ms]
20.11.2020 08:18:22.021 INFO  [main] o.a.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi:285   - Connection check threshold is calculated: 10000
20.11.2020 08:19:19.373 INFO  [tcp-disco-srvr-[:47500]-#3] o.a.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi:285   - TCP discovery accepted incoming connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.92.175, rmtPort=56962]
20.11.2020 08:19:19.389 INFO  [tcp-disco-srvr-[:47500]-#3] o.a.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi:285   - TCP discovery spawning a new thread for connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.92.175, rmtPort=56962]
20.11.2020 08:19:19.389 INFO  [tcp-disco-sock-reader-[]-#4] o.a.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi:285   - Started serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.92.175:56962, rmtPort=56962]
20.11.2020 08:19:19.389 INFO  [tcp-disco-sock-reader-[9f44068b 192.168.92.175:56962 client]-#4] o.a.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi:285   - Initialized connection with remote client node [nodeId=9f44068b-b8ca-4d8b-bb32-efd2e2a1940c, rmtAddr=/192.168.92.175:56962]
20.11.2020 08:19:19.498 INFO  [tcp-disco-sock-reader-[9f44068b 192.168.92.175:56962 client]-#4] o.a.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi:285   - Finished serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.92.175:56962, rmtPort=56962
20.11.2020 08:20:21.287 INFO  [tcp-disco-srvr-[:47500]-#3] o.a.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi:285   - TCP discovery accepted incoming connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.92.176, rmtPort=55941]
20.11.2020 08:20:21.287 INFO  [tcp-disco-srvr-[:47500]-#3] o.a.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi:285   - TCP discovery spawning a new thread for connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.92.176, rmtPort=55941]
20.11.2020 08:20:21.287 INFO  [tcp-disco-sock-reader-[]-#5] o.a.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi:285   - Started serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.92.176:55941, rmtPort=55941]
20.11.2020 08:20:21.287 INFO  [tcp-disco-sock-reader-[6a50abff 192.168.92.176:55941]-#5] o.a.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi:285   - Initialized connection with remote server node [nodeId=6a50abff-8cfd-4b3a-b894-54fa9d405d36, rmtAddr=/192.168.92.176:55941]
20.11.2020 08:20:21.287 INFO  [tcp-disco-sock-reader-[6a50abff 192.168.92.176:55941]-#5] o.a.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi:285   - Finished serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.92.176:55941, rmtPort=55941
20.11.2020 08:20:26.239 INFO  [tcp-disco-srvr-[:47500]-#3] o.a.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi:285   - TCP discovery accepted incoming connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.92.175, rmtPort=56996]
... it continues like that till the join or failure
```

The logs log the same on all servers. In this case server 1 and 2 create a cluster after 7 minutes. server 3 fails after 9 minutes due to incompatible baseline topology. After reseting the failed server it can rejoin the cluster. The behavior only happens sometimes. Most of the time the servers rebuild the cluster without problem.

Comment: Do you have baseline auto-adjust? I imagine that baseline may be changed before the 3rd node is added.

Comment: Yes baseline auto adjust ist active. But why does ist take so long for the join? The Servers are restarted simultanously and should all be joining within several seconds of each other. So auto baselining should not be an issue if the join works as expected.

Comment: Maybe the other nodes did not finish restoring local partition state? Reading WAL and restoring partition state may take up to a few minutes. It is recommended to deactivate cluster before shutting it down to make start-up faster.

Comment: The persisted data is actually just a couple of kilobyte. I don't think it should take long to load it. In most of the cases the joins haben instantanously. When the loading of the data would take this long (a couple of minutes) it would always be this long

Comment: Looks like some network problems with Discovery. Maybe a slow DNS? I recommend collecting a stack trace when you see it hanging, see what's going on there.